# Mocking View with RhinoMocks

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

We are using MVP (Supervising Controller) for ASP.NET WebForms with 3.5 SP1.

What is the preferred way to check the value of a view property that only has the a set operation with RhinoMocks?

Here is what we have so far:

```
var service = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFooService>();
// stub some data for the method used in OnLoad in the presenter

var view = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFooView>();
var presenter = new FooPresenter(view, service);

view.Raise(v => v.Load += null, this, EventArgs.Empty);

Assert.IsTrue(view.Bars.Count == 10); // there is no get on Bars
```

Should we use Expects or another way, any input would be great.

Thanks

***Update based on Darin Dimitrov's reply.***

```
var bars = new List<Bar>() { new Bar() { BarId = 1 } };

var fooService = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFooService>();

// this is called in OnLoad in the Presenter
fooService.Stub(x => x.GetBars()).Return(bars);

var view = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFooView>();
var presenter = new FooPresenter(view, fooService);

view.Raise(v => v.Load += null, this, EventArgs.Empty);
view.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Bars = bars); // this does not pass
```

This doesn't work.  Should I be testing it this way or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could assert that the `setter` on the `Bars` property has been called with a correct argument. Assuming the `Bars` property is an array of strings:

```
// arrange
var view = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFooView>();
var bars = new[] { "bars" };

// act
view.Bars = bars;

// assert
view.AssertWasCalled(
    x => { x.Bars = bars; }
);
```

This should also work:

```
view.AssertWasCalled(
    x => { x.Bars = new[] { "abc" }; }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it makes sense.  I have updated my question based on your help.